# TinyMCE configuration to allow font tags

Tags: fonts, tinymce, wysiwyg

Configuring TinyMCE to allow for  tags, based on a customer requirement.
 My config is as follows (grabbed from the TinyMCE samples; sorry for the length,
 I didn't want to leave anyting out:

```
tinyMCE.init({apply_source_formatting : true,  
              button_tile_map : true,          
              content_css : '/themes/site_themes/default/styles/editor.css',      
              document_base_url : '/',  
              editor_selector : 'lg_mceEditor',  
              external_image_list_url : "/inc/imagelist.js/",  
              external_link_list_url : "/inc/linklist.js",  
              fix_list_elements : true,  
              force_p_newlines : true,  
              forced_root_block : 'p',  
              heading_clear_tag : 'p',  
              mode:'textareas',  
              paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,  
             plugins :'contextmenu,inlinepopups,nonbreaking,paste,style,table,xhtmlxtras',   
              relative_urls : false,  
              theme : 'advanced',  
              theme_advanced_blockformats : 'p,h2,h3,h4,h5',  
theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'cut,copy,paste,pasteword,undo,redo,|,removeformat,formatselect,|,bold,italic,abbr,ins,del,|,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,|,link,unlink,image,|,code',  
              theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'fontsizeselect,forecolorpicker',     
              theme_advanced_buttons3 : '',  
              theme_advanced_path_location : 'bottom',  
              theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,  
              theme_advanced_resizing : true,  
              theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',  
              theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',  
  entities : '160,nbsp,38,amp,162,cent,8364,euro,163,pound,165,yen,169,copy,174,reg,8482,trade,8240,permil,181,micro,183,middot,8226,bull,8230,hellip,8242,prime,8243,Prime,167,sect,182,para,223,szlig,8249,lsaquo,8250,rsaquo,171,laquo,187,raquo,8216,lsquo,8217,rsquo,8220,ldquo,8221,rdquo,8218,sbquo,8222,bdquo,60,lt,62,gt,8804,le,8805,ge,8211,ndash,8212,mdash,175,macr,8254,oline,164,curren,166,brvbar,168,uml,161,iexcl,191,iquest,710,circ,732,tilde,176,deg,8722,minus,177,plusmn,247,divide,8260,frasl,215,times,185,sup1,178,sup2,179,sup3,188,frac14,189,frac12,190,frac34,402,fnof,8747,int,8721,sum,8734,infin,8730,radic,8764,sim,8773,cong,8776,asymp,8800,ne,8801,equiv,8712,isin,8713,notin,8715,ni,8719,prod,8743,and,8744,or,172,not,8745,cap,8746,cup,8706,part,8704,forall,8707,exist,8709,empty,8711,nabla,8727,lowast,8733,prop,8736,ang,180,acute,184,cedil,170,ordf,186,ordm,8224,dagger,8225,Dagger,192,Agrave,194,Acirc,195,Atilde,196,Auml,197,Aring,198,AElig,199,Ccedil,200,Egrave,202,Ecirc,203,Euml,204,Igrave,206,Icirc,207,Iuml,208,ETH,209,Ntilde,210,Ograve,212,Ocirc,213,Otilde,214,Ouml,216,Oslash,338,OElig,217,Ugrave,219,Ucirc,220,Uuml,376,Yuml,222,THORN,224,agrave,226,acirc,227,atilde,228,auml,229,aring,230,aelig,231,ccedil,232,egrave,234,ecirc,235,euml,236,igrave,238,icirc,239,iuml,240,eth,241,ntilde,242,ograve,244,ocirc,245,otilde,246,ouml,248,oslash,339,oelig,249,ugrave,251,ucirc,252,uuml,254,thorn,255,yuml,914,Beta,915,Gamma,916,Delta,917,Epsilon,918,Zeta,919,Eta,920,Theta,921,Iota,922,Kappa,923,Lambda,924,Mu,925,Nu,926,Xi,927,Omicron,928,Pi,929,Rho,931,Sigma,932,Tau,933,Upsilon,934,Phi,935,Chi,936,Psi,937,Omega,945,alpha,946,beta,947,gamma,948,delta,949,epsilon,950,zeta,951,eta,952,theta,953,iota,954,kappa,955,lambda,956,mu,957,nu,958,xi,959,omicron,960,pi,961,rho,962,sigmaf,963,sigma,964,tau,965,upsilon,966,phi,967,chi,968,psi,969,omega,8501,alefsym,982,piv,8476,real,977,thetasym,978,upsih,8472,weierp,8465,image,8592,larr,8593,uarr,8594,rarr,8595,darr,8596,harr,8629,crarr,8656,lArr,8657,uArr,8658,rArr,8659,dArr,8660,hArr,8756,there4,8834,sub,8835,sup,8836,nsub,8838,sube,8839,supe,8853,oplus,8855,otimes,8869,perp,8901,sdot,8968,lceil,8969,rceil,8970,lfloor,8971,rfloor,9001,lang,9002,rang,9674,loz,9824,spades,9827,clubs,9829,hearts,9830,diams,8194,ensp,8195,emsp,8201,thinsp,8204,zwnj,8205,zwj,8206,lrm,8207,rlm,173,shy,233,eacute,237,iacute,243,oacute,250,uacute,193,Aacute,225,aacute,201,Eacute,205,Iacute,211,Oacute,218,Uacute,221,Yacute,253,yacute',  
               valid_elements : ''  
               +'a[class|href|rel|rev|tabindex|title],'  
               +'abbr[class|title],'  
               +'blockquote[cite|class],'  
               +'br[],'  
               +'cite[class],'  
               +'dd[class],'  
               +'del[cite|class|datetime],'  
               +'dfn[class],'  
               +'div[class],'  
               +'dl[class],'  
               +'dt[class],'  
               +'em/i[class],'  
               +'h1[class],'  
               +'h2[class],'  
               +'h3[class],'  
               +'h4[class],'  
               +'h5[class],'  
               +'hr[class|noshade<noshade|size],'  
               +'img[align<bottom?left?middle?right?top|alt|class|height|longdesc|src|title||width],'  
               +'ins[cite|class|datetime],'  
               +'li[class|type],'  
               +'ol[class|start|type],'  
               +'p[class],'  
               +'pre/listing/plaintext/xmp[class],'  
               +'q[cite|class],'  
               +'small[class],'  
               +'span[class],'  
               +'strong/b[class],'  
               +'sub[class],'  
               +'sup[class],'  
               +'table[class|id|summary|title],'  
               +'td[colspan|rowspan],'  
               +'th[colspan|rowspan],'  
               +'tr[rowspan],'  
               +'ul[class|id|title|type],'  
               +'font[class|color|dir<ltr?rtl|face|id|lang|size|style|title]'});
```

So the editor UI seems to work fine, but when I use the view html button or save it back to the server, it looks like font is still getting stripped out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  I mistakenly thought that tinyMCE uses the font tag still for the color/size stuff.  Looks like this version is using the span with an attached style attribute.  So I had to change the line that says +'span[class],' to +'span[class|style],'